# Check documents not existing at elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have millions of indexed documents. after indexing I figured that there is an document count mismatch. i want to send array of hundreds of document ids and search at Elastic search if those document ids exists?. and in response get ids that has not Indexed.

example:
these are indexed documents

```
[497499, 497550, 498370, 498476, 498639, 498726, 498826, 500479, 500780, 500918]
```

I'm sending 4 at a time

```
[497599, 88888, 497550, 77777]
```

response should be whats not at there

```
[88888, 77777]
```

Comment: Did you try a Terms-Query on "_id" field with a boolean query ("must_not") ?

Comment: @Benjamin - imho , thats answer than comment.

Comment: hope now the description is more clear @Benjamin

Comment: @NirmalI update the description "must_not" didn't work for me

Comment: How could you get in results a document id that hasn't been index?  what you can do is to run the "ids" query . it will give you in results which document exists and then you will continue with the logic.

Comment: @AssaelAzran I can do that in mysql. transform args to a table and use "except" query. I don't know from ES

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `_mget` endpoint and then parse the result like for instance :

```
GET someidx/_mget?_source=false
{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id" : "c37m5W4BifZmUly9Ni-X"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Result :

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "_index" : "someidx",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "c37m5W4BifZmUly9Ni-X",
      "_version" : 1,
      "_seq_no" : 0,
      "_primary_term" : 1,
      "found" : true
    },
    {
      "_index" : "someidx",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "2",
      "found" : false
    }
  ]
}
```